# InstaSlider slider/carousel plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugin, instagram

InstaSlider is a lightweight jQuery image slider / carousel plugin that populates content from an Instagram hashtag.

After searching for a similar solution for one of my own projects with no luck I decided there might be others who would benefit from this.

It is the bare minimum function at the moment so there will be more features and updates added soon!

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/pCQkF/1/)

```
(function($, window, document, undefined){

    var InstaSlider = {

        init: function(options, container){

            var self = this;
                self.container = container,
                self.$container = $(container),
                self.current = 0, // Set current to 0 on initialise
                self.imgWidth = self.$container.width(); // img width will be the same as the container

                self.options = $.extend({}, $.fn.instaSlider.options, options);

                self.imgLength = self.options.limit;

                this.createSlider(); // Create the slider

                self.sliderUL = self.$container.find('.instaslider-wrapper ul');
        },

        createSlider: function(){
            // create the slider
            var slider = this.$container.append('<div class="instaslider-wrapper"><ul></ul></div>');

            this.createNav();
            this.createSlides();

        },

        createNav: function() {

            var self = this;
            // create the navigation for the slider
            var buttonPrev = '<button class="' + this.options.prevClass + '" data-direction="prev">Prev</button>',
                buttonNext = '<button class="' + this.options.nextClass + '" data-direction="next">Next</button>',
                nav = '<div class="instaslider-nav">' + buttonPrev + buttonNext + '</div>';

            // append it to the container
            this.$container.append(nav);

            // when a button is clicked set current
            this.$container.find('button').on('click', function(){
                self.setCurrent( $(this).data('direction') );
                self.transition();
            });

        },

        fetch: function() {

            // Set the endpoint

            var endpoint = 'https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/' + this.options.hash + '/media/recent?client_id=' + this.options.clientID;   

            //fetch images from instagram

            return $.ajax({
                url: endpoint,
                data: {},
                dataType: 'jsonp',
                type:'GET'
            });

        },

        createSlides: function() {
            // create the slides
            var self = this,
                container = this.$container,
                sliderUL = container.find('.instaslider-wrapper ul');           

            self.fetch().done(function(results){

                // Limit the amount of results
                results = self.limit( results.data, self.options.limit );
                // loop over results create a slider for each one.
                self.slides = $.map(results, function(obj, i){
                    var img = '<li><img src="' + results[i].images.standard_resolution.url + '" /></li>';
                    sliderUL.append(img);
                });

            });

            self.fetch().fail(function(){
                sliderUL.remove();
                container.html('<div class="error"><p>Sorry,<br /> Could not fetch images at this time.</p></div>');
            })

        },

        setCurrent: function(direction) {
            // set the current slide and handle direction here
            var self = this;
            var pos = self.current;
            pos += ( ~~(direction === 'next') || -1);
            self.current = ( pos < 0 ) ? self.imgLength -1 : pos % self.imgLength;
            return pos;
        },

        transition: function() {
            // handle animation and slide transition here
            var self = this;

            self.sliderUL.stop().animate({
                'margin-left': -( this.current * this.imgWidth )
            });
        },

        limit: function(obj, count) {
            return obj.slice( 0, count );
        },

    };

    $.fn.instaSlider = function(options){
        return this.each(function(){
            var instaSlider = Object.create( InstaSlider );
            instaSlider.init(options, this);
            $.data(this, 'instaSlider', instaSlider);
        });
    };

    /*----------------------------------------------------------------
        Default Options
    ----------------------------------------------------------------*/

    $.fn.instaSlider.options = {

        // Default Options
        clientID: null,
        hash:'photooftheday',
        prevClass: 'prev',
        nextClass: 'next',
        limit: 5,
    }

})(jQuery, window, document, undefined);
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you'd really benefit looking at either jQuery UI's widget factory or (my preference) using some boilerplate such as [jQuery Boilerplate](http://jqueryboilerplate.com/).

Other than that, in no particular order:

1. `$.fn.instaSlider.options = {...` I've never seen anyone do this
   and I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve with it. Just have
   your defaults as a local variable within the IIFE and close over it.
2. You're creating a new endpoint variable on every call of
   `fetch()`. Create it once in init e.g. `self.endPoint = 'theUrl'`
3. `self.imgLength = self.options.limit;` this is pointless.
4. I don't think that you should have prev and next classes as an option, just name them uniquely e.g. 'instaSlider-next' - it's the kind of customisation that most people would never want or need.
5. `createNav` has no need for all 3 variables, just create one and build the entire html string and append it.
6. Don't use `<br />` tags for spacing - people will come and eat you.

I'd say you're on the right track - just a bit of polishing here and there.

Comment: Thanks! Those are some really useful pointers. I was debating leaving the next/prev classes as fixed but I know in the past i've used plugins that had similar names and so I thought i'd just leave that in incase.